# Runtime Err in Web.Config File

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-hosting

This might be a strange question but I am stuck. I am hosting my webpage to my company`s web hosting service. When I am putting the published files it is throwing me this err:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This is what my Web.config looks like:

```
    <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
    </customErrors>
```

Comment: please give full definition of your web.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the mode to Off and then see what the error actually is.

If the error is still very vague, then it is possibly an error in the web.config it's self.

Comment: I did that, but still the same err.

Comment: look through your web.config and see if there are any errors in it. you might have some type-o's or such which is causing your application to break before it has hit any code